# Reorder through Css

Tags: css

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="inner-div">
        <div class="child-div">Order 1</div>
        <div class="child-div">Order 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-div">
        <div class="child-div">Order 3</div>
        <div class="child-div">Order 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### I want this order but we can't change the html can we do this only through CSS

Order-3
Order-1
Order-4
Order-2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf1Y4.jpg)

Comment: not possible with this markup. If they would share all the same containers, you could use the `order` property to reorder in flexbox and grid. You also could use `grid-area` within grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Couple `order` with `display:flex` and `display:contents` to omit the `.inner-div`s boxes and make the `.child-div` boxes the flex items.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  gap: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.child-div {
  border: 3px solid #ee1b24;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #ee1b24;
}
.inner-div {
  display:contents;
}
.child-div:first-child {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="inner-div">
        <div class="child-div">Order 1</div>
        <div class="child-div">Order 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-div">
        <div class="child-div">Order 3</div>
        <div class="child-div">Order 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```